# JList are hiding the center border in Borderlayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to display two empty `JList` instances in East and West borders to which I would add elements dynamically in a program.

I am facing following problem:

1. The `leftall` and `rightall` functionality isn't working as required. These buttons are meant to shift all elements to the left list and right list respectively.

---

```
   public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Challange");
        Container c = getContentPane();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(10);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
        jp.add(textfield);
        jp.add(btn);
        c.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        DefaultListModel<String> listmodel1 = new DefaultListModel<>();
        DefaultListModel<String> listmodel2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
        JList<String> list = new JList<>(listmodel1);
        JList<String> list1 = new JList<>(listmodel2);
        c.add(new JScrollPane(list),BorderLayout.WEST);
        c.add(new JScrollPane(list1),BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,0));
        JButton right = new JButton(">");
        JButton rightall = new JButton(">>");
        JButton left = new JButton("<");
        JButton leftall = new JButton("<<");
        jp1.add(right);
        jp1.add(rightall);
        jp1.add(left);
        jp1.add(leftall);
        c.add(jp1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Action action = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String text = textfield.getText();
                if(!text.equals("")){
                    listmodel1.addElement(text);
                }
                textfield.setText("");
            }
        };
        textfield.addActionListener(action);
        btn.addActionListener(action);

        JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");
        remove.setEnabled(false);
        c.add(remove, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                remove.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        remove.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                List<String> selecteditem = list.getSelectedValuesList();

                for(String items:selecteditem){
                    listmodel1.removeElement(items);
                }
            }

        });

        left.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                List<String> selecteditem = list1.getSelectedValuesList();

                for(String items:selecteditem){
                    listmodel1.addElement(items);
                    listmodel2.removeElement(items);
                }
            }
        });

        right.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                List<String> selecteditem = list.getSelectedValuesList();

                for(String items:selecteditem){
                    listmodel2.addElement(items);
                    listmodel1.removeElement(items);
                }
            }
        });

        rightall.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                ListModel<String> selecteditem = list.getModel();

                for(int i=0; i<selecteditem.getSize();i++){
                    listmodel2.addElement(selecteditem.getElementAt(i));
                    listmodel1.removeElement(selecteditem.getElementAt(i));
                }
            }
        });

        leftall.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                ListModel<String> selecteditem = list1.getModel();

                for(int i=0; i<selecteditem.getSize();i++){
                    listmodel1.addElement(selecteditem.getElementAt(i));
                    listmodel2.removeElement(selecteditem.getElementAt(i));
                }
            }
        });
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyFrame mf = new MyFrame();
       mf.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Put something visible in the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout` (e.g. some text in a `JLabel`) then change `MyFrame mf = new MyFrame(); mf.setVisible(true);` to add `mf.pack();` between the two statements.

Comment: *"I am facing two problems:"* Then the best approach is to start two question threads, each with a [mre] specific to that problem. In this case, none of the listeners are relevant to a layout problem, while the layout is mostly irrelevant to a problem about shifting one list model to another - which itself only requires two buttons and two lists as components.

Comment: I am putting buttons in the center. Wouldn't that do it?

Comment: *"Wouldn't that do it?"* Packing the frame. Have you done that?